# How is it possible that a Big Bang happened instead of becoming trapped as a Kugelblitz?

Tags: black-hole, astrophysics, big-bang-theory

I was reading about [Kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)) on Wikipedia, and it says that if enough energy gets concentrated it leads to a black hole (from where nothing can escape - supposedly). So, if during the Big-Bang, when all the energy of the universe was in a really small region of space, why didn't it lead to a black hole and stay forever like that?

Comment: A bh is an object in space, but not space itself

Comment: Please see [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208)

Comment: Related: [Observable universe equals its Schwarzschild radius (event horizon)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32443/5264)

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible that some black holes (called primordial black holes) were formed in the early universe, in general most of the matter-energy did not collapse into these, since while extremely dense, early universe was also extremely uniform: there simply wasn't significant enough concentrations of mass-energy to form such black holes before the universe expanded rapidly in the inflation phase.